# Cloud Dataflow to Join multiple files

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-datalab

I am newbie to Google Cloud,I have below files in GCS, need to design a dataflow to merge the files and replace values from product,location files and load the final output file to BigQuery.

1. gs://testprojectxxxx/staging/actual_file.csv
2. gs://testprojectxxxx/staging_timestamp/product.csv
                                     /location.csv

[image]

**Python code on local machine:**

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/xxxx\\actual_file.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/xxxx_folder\\product.csv",header=None,names=['id', 'product_name'])
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', left_on='product_id', right_on='id')
df3.drop(['product_id_x', 'id'], axis=1,inplace=True)

df4 = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/xxxx_folder\\location.csv",header=None,names=['id', 'location_name'])
df5 = pd.merge(df3, df4, how='left', left_on='location_id', right_on='id')
df5.drop(['location_id_x', 'id'], axis=1,inplace=True)

df5.rename(columns={'product_name_y':'product_name','location_name_y':'location'}, inplace=True)
df5.to_csv('Final_file.csv', sep=',',encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

To join these rows you want to use `GroupByKey` or `CoGroupByKey`

https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.8.0/apache_beam.transforms.core.html#apache_beam.transforms.core.GroupByKey

Check out Section 4.2.3 in the docs https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#core-beam-transforms

```
emails_list = [
    ('amy', 'amy@example.com'),
    ('carl', 'carl@example.com'),
    ('julia', 'julia@example.com'),
    ('carl', 'carl@email.com'),
]
phones_list = [
    ('amy', '111-222-3333'),
    ('james', '222-333-4444'),
    ('amy', '333-444-5555'),
    ('carl', '444-555-6666'),
]

emails = p | 'CreateEmails' >> beam.Create(emails_list)
phones = p | 'CreatePhones' >> beam.Create(phones_list)

# The result PCollection contains one key-value element for each key in the
# input PCollections. The key of the pair will be the key from the input and
# the value will be a dictionary with two entries: 'emails' - an iterable of
# all values for the current key in the emails PCollection and 'phones': an
# iterable of all values for the current key in the phones PCollection.
results = ({'emails': emails, 'phones': phones}
           | beam.CoGroupByKey())

def join_info(name_info):
  (name, info) = name_info
  return '%s; %s; %s' %\
      (name, sorted(info['emails']), sorted(info['phones']))

contact_lines = results | beam.Map(join_info)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, Initially the files are decompressed and copied into the new folder of the staging bucket. I have 2 questions
    1. how to trigger the dataflow when the file arrives.
    2. how to set the path in dataflow to pick the new files. 
    
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
      parser.add_argument('--input',
                          dest='input',
                          default='gs://dataflow-samples/',
                          help='Input file to process.')

Comment: I dont think dataflow is able to 'listen' for new files. Ideally, the mechanism that uploads the file would then launch dataflow for those specific files. Otherwise you could setup an cron job in app engine to launch every 5 minutes and check for files. If the cron job finds files it should move them to a different folder (In order to differentiate new files from old files), and then launch dataflow for those paths https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/googlecloudstorageclient/functions